# Dache Giving OutOfMemory Exception

Tags: dache

I am trying the Dache Distrubuted Caching from https://www.dache.io/
created a simple sample
with just a string added to the cache and trying to retrieve it.
the code as below

To Add

```
ASP.CacheProvider._cacheClient.AddOrUpdate("test",10);
```

To Get

```
string strValue;
bool blnSuccess = ASP.CacheProvider._cacheClient.TryGet<string>("test", out strValue);
```

where I have made the variable _cacheClient in class ASP.CacheProvider to public

now when adding the item to cache it gives me error

> "An exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in Dache.Core.dll but was not handled in user code"

in the method Extract in class "DacheProtocolHelper"

can any one help?

regards
Aravind.

Comment: What version of Dache Host? What version of Dache Client?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're maybe mixing versions of Dache, as the communication protocol changed in 1.4.8. Please ensure that both the Client and Host are the same version, and when in doubt upgrade to newest version (1.5.2).

NuGet: [Dache.Client](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Dache.Client) and [Dache.CacheHost](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Dache.CacheHost).

Comment: i am using the latest version 1.5.2 for both client and the host. and also when i debug i can see the connection is going offline and the host is added into _offlineCacheHost. can you send me maybe a working sample so i check that.

Comment: sorry you are right, there was another instance of the host running with the older version. now the sample works fine. thanks.